# Improve query efficiency by removing casting and functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-update, where-clause

I have the following query which works as expected.

It updates if a matching id exists and timestamp falls within the range I am looking for.

I am not able to validate against an exact timestamp value as the request coming in will only match timing approximately (missing by a few milliseconds) thus having to find a match by truncating it as follows.

```
UPDATE myTable SET code=1, WHERE id=50 
and 
start_ts >= date_trunc('day', cast('2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000' as TIMESTAMP))
and 
start_ts < date_trunc('day', cast('2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000' as TIMESTAMP)) + interval '1 day';
```

Is there a way to do this without having to use the date_trunc method and castings, or at least reduce the casting to be only performed once since it is a repetition?

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Your query is fine.  All the operations are on constants, so they are handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine.  For performance, you want an index on `myTable(id, start_ts)`.

Comment: Noted. Not gonna be able to add further indexing just yet. When you say constants do you mean cast('2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000' as TIMESTAMP) is actually not being done twice?

Comment: @karvai: it's done twice but before the query is started. And the overhead of doing that twice is really negligible

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you should be able to do:

```
update mytable set code=1
where 
    id=50 
    and start_ts >= '2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000'::date
    and start_ts <  '2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000'::date + interval '1 day';
```

Comment: The equivalent of `date_trunc('day', cast('2020-10-03 13:34:51.947000' as TIMESTAMP))` would be `timestamp '2020-10-03 00:00:00'`

Comment: Is this the same, as in underneath the hood it is still a date trunc and casting going on? Thus no diff in performance. Snooping thru the docs as am typing this to see references to this. I do find this more readable. Thanks.

Comment: @karvai: changing this expression does not result in any significant performance gain, no matter how you phrase it (that's a constant value, that's evaluated only once - or twice, not for every row). My answer was focusing on the "simplification" part of your question.